# How do I keep track of the Forge API cost?

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-designautomation

I am writing a node.js app which uses the autodesk forge design automation and model derivatives API. The cost of using the API is calculated with the processing time for the design automation API, and by job for the model derivatives API. I cannot find much information about the pricing other than this url: https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing

How do I keep track of the API processing time in case of the design automation API? Is it by tracking how long it takes to get a response when I make a http request?

Comment: Design Automation API is billed based on the processing time of a job. Please refer to https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/estimate-design-automation-costs for more details

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, it answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emma's answer is spot on! Adding to that, we also have a simple cost calculator you might find helpful: https://forge-calculator.autodesk.io (source code: https://github.com/augustogoncalves/forge-calculator).